# Where should I chain multiple network requests in MVVM? UseCases or Repository?

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java2, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am refactoring our codebase. Right now we have a singleton Repository which ceates network requests and manages operators chaining with RxJava and Kotlin Coroutines.

However that Repository is being injected into multiple ViewModels and becomes harder to mantain.

I would like to abstract our codebase and integrate some useCases. As far as I know it is general opinion to use a single network request in useCase, this is why I am unsure about chaining network requests.

I need to chain multiple network requests using **Observable.zip and RxJava Subjects.**

Would the following flow be correct approach?

Viewmodel calls useCase, which creates network request(from repository), handles that network request, creates **a LiveData** and forwards that LiveData to ViewModel and also **updates subject from the Repository**, so that Repository could **emit some data** after all network requests have finished?

Then our Repository remains similar to our current approach with less code and will only be responsible for multiple network requests chaining.

I hope I was clear enough. I have investigated multiple MVVM examples, but they seemed not practical for real applications, with **complex networking logic**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not chain different API calls in repository. Mapping to more complex domain objects should be done in a use case. Usually there is more than one repository, each of them is responsible for some part of business domain models (e.g. UsersRepository, PostsRepository, etc). Use case can depend on multiple repositories.

[Example (Plaid app)](https://github.com/android/plaid/blob/master/designernews/src/main/java/io/plaidapp/designernews/domain/GetCommentsWithRepliesAndUsersUseCase.kt)

Comment: Yes I also looked a lot into Plaid app. The problem is that I need to observe results of API chaining in multiple ViewModels. As far as I know useCase should be used for one ViewModel. Or am I incorrect?

Comment: Yes, single usecase instance should be used by one view model (you must provide separate instances of same use case class for each view model) But what do you exactly mean by API chaining?

Comment: For istance we make 4 network requests, and we need to observe them all, before creating a new network request from whatever viewmodel user wants.

Comment: Create a use case or component that makes the 4 requests. Then in each view model invoke that use case and wait for results (it may be an Observable if you use RxJava) before calling next use cases.

Comment: Thanks! However, one more thing. 4 network requests are not getting called at the same time. Only after particular user interactions. So should I still follow you sugestion? It does make sense :)

Comment: That should still be fine :-)

Comment: Thanks! I will accept answer! However in the end multiple ViewModels will still have access to same useCase.. It will look like our repository... Should I make it singleton then?

Comment: You provide separate instance of same use case for each view model. Don't make use case a singleton.

Comment: To be clear: a use case doesn't do requests directly but through repositories. Each repository can implement some synchronization mechanizm to prevent calling simultaneous requests to same endpoint at same time.